# How can I use both filter and filter_complex with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to generate a waveform using this command :

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=600x200,colorkey=black,colorchannelmixer=rr=156/255:gg=244/255:bb=47/255[fg]; \
color=s=600x200:color=#44582c,drawgrid=width=iw/10:height=ih/5:color=#9cf42f@0.1[bg]; \
[bg][fg]overlay=format=rgb" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

And then crop it using

```
ffmpeg -i output.png -vf  "crop=600:40:0:80" output-cropped.png
```

How can I combine the two in a single ffmpeg (latest git: version N-80640-gf573acc) invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=600x200,colorkey=black, \
      colorchannelmixer=rr=156/255:gg=244/255:bb=47/255[fg]; \
      color=s=600x200:color=#44582c,drawgrid=width=iw/10:height=ih/5:color=#9cf42f@0.1[bg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=format=rgb,crop=600:40:0:80" -frames:v 1 output-cropped.png
```